# hide element whit javascript dom and remove the empty spaces

Tags: javascript

This is my code but it's not good because they do not line up.
I have to remove the empty spaces, and group the process bars

[image]

```
function clickMe(abc) {
  var v = document.getElementsByClassName(abc);
  hidden('.progress');
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i = i + 1) {
    v[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

function hidden(elemnt) {
  var hide = document.querySelectorAll(elemnt);
  for (var i = 0; i < hide.length; i = i + 1) {
    hide[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}
```

When I click, I compare

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit this line of your code

```
 var v=document.getElementsByClassName(abc);
 hidden('.progress');
```

to

```
var v=document.getElementsByClassName(abc);
hidden(v);
```

and set visibility to none.

Comment: is not work beacuse                                                                                                          `<button class="btn btn" id="other" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">other</button> `                                                                                   `<div class="progress framework all">
<span class="pull-right">90%</span><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">text</div></div>`